# Python Montor asyncio with srv remote connection is being refused by mondodb

Tags: python, mongodb, motor-asyncio

I've been working with pymongo module to connect to mongodb for a while and I haven't had any problems with it, but now, I have to process some heavy info (about 1 million docs daily or so) and I wanted to try the async module Motor to work with. But, I couldn't get it to work. Accordingly with the documentation, it says that the motor.MotorClient or motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient should work as the pymongo.Client which receives a string with the srv connection and that should be it, but every time that i try with motor clients, it throws back the next error:

> All nameservers failed to answer the query
>   cluster-host. IN SRV: Server some-ip UDP port 53 answered REFUSED; Server some-ip UDP port 53
>   answered The DNS operation timed out.; Server some-ip UDP port
>   53 answered REFUSED

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the minimum snippet of code that reproduces the problem, the complete error message, and the stack trace?

Comment: It would be these the to client instances that I'd have been trying: 
   `motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(mongo_connection_string)`, 
   `motor.MotorClient(mongo_connection_string)`.
The erros is that that I posted up there.

Comment: @JuanSebastianMontoyaContrer Have to found a solution to this?

Comment: I certainly wont remember something of 2 almost 3 years ago. I had to find a way around it's the only thing I remember.  Sorry :(